# Topic of the Week?

Tags: discussion

As our question per day have been too low. Is it not right to increase it by occasional Topic of the week?

It has been done over [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week) on weekly basis and now restarted on occasional basis.

Can we also start Topic of the week on occasional basis on festival like on Maha Shivratri asking question on [shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva) , on Holi topic should be [holi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holi), 9 days TOW on Navaratri etc etc.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. I support this.

Comment: I think this will be great

Comment: Loved the idea, am bit busy these days so we can discuss over this by inviting community members of Hinduism.SE and answer here their suggestions, recommendations.

Comment: Just want to drop by and consider reading [a very related post on MSE about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work). Wishing you the best for the site's growth :)

Comment: I like the idea.

Comment: It can be the good initiative.